# What is the longest lightsaber blade ever seen

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

The only thing I can think of is this scene from visions (non canonical to legends **OR** canon)[image]

What is the longest in Canon or legends?

Comment: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/lightsaber.png

Comment: There's some very long lightsabers in SW: Visions; https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRa6D.png

Comment: Reminds me of [that scene](https://youtu.be/pPkWZdluoUg) in _Spaceballs_...

Comment: The length is supposed to be adjustable, e.g. to allow Yoda to use other Jedi's lightsabers.  According to canon sources, there's a  slider at the bottom that can make it go longer, the only problem is that it's [super sensitive](https://youtu.be/lWxnwSFpX-s?t=148) that's why they don't use it too often.

Answer (score 16):

### Canon

Assuming the lightsabers in [*Star Wars: The Lightsaber Collection*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Lightsaber_Collection) are shown accurately to scale, the longest lightsaber ***from emitter to tip*** is the curved handle used by Asajj Ventress during the Clone Wars.

The Darksaber is *marginally* longer, but it's arguably not a lightsaber.

[image]

### Legends

Keiran Halcyon has a very large (3 meter) lightsaber in *[I, Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/I,_Jedi)*.

> I rotated my right wrist, twisting the throttle control up, and
> whipped the lightsaber around in a slash aimed to slice the deadHutt
> switch in two. With the twist I turned the lightsaber’s emerald out of
> the way and **I brought the diamond into line with the Durindfire beam.
> This extended the blade from 133 centimeters to 300,** narrowing it, but
> bringing the Hutt’s hand easily into striking range. Quick flick of
> the wrist, cleave the control in two, and the day would be saved. That
> would be the easy way.

---